# Не получается эффект меню с Css

Tags: jquery, css

Как сделать что бы стрелки прилягаля вплотную к тексту, тоесть что бы было обтекание не зависимо сколько написано текста.

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/7/

А как оно будет менять на другую стрелку при клике на блок ?
Это не правильный ответ в комментарии.

Comment: я бы кстати, вместо checkbox радиобуттон сделал:
http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить стрелки как <img>, а не бэкграунд. [Смотрите тут](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/8/)

**UPD**

> А как оно будет менять на другую
> стрелку при клике на блок ?

Вариантов - море. [Вот один из них](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/9/).

Comment: @Dionis как-то некошерно полностью css решение превращать в решение на js, http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/11/ (@sasha1 - я не чистил css сильно от лишнего кода, так-что если будете использовать, сделайте)